# Cannot save to database or retrieve (right info) from it

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, console, sql-server-ce

I am saving data to the database "successfully", using:

```
try
{
    // Save the new Client now.
    Profile profile = new Profile()
    {
        Salutation = Salutation,
        FirstName = FirstName,
        MiddleName = MiddleName,
        LastName = LastName,
        Gender = Gender,
        DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth,

        CompanyName = ClientCompanyName,
        StreetAddress = StreetAddress,
        Suburb = Suburb,
        PostCode = PostCode,
        State = State,
        Country = Country,

        ABN = ABN.ToString(),
        ACN = ACN.ToString(),

        TelephoneNumber = TelephoneNumber,
        MobileNumber = MobileNumber,
        EmailAddress = EmailAddress
    };
    database.Profiles.Add(profile);
    database.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("Client saved.");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.InnerException);
}
```

and it says it's been saved. But when I look in the database - *nothing's there!*

And, when I try to get the first name of the person I just added, it returns the entire SELECT statement - *not their first name*:

`var hisname = database.Profiles.Where(x => x.FirstName == "Jase");`

What gives?

This is a C# Windows Console application.

The same code works on my *website*.

## Update

This is what it returns to me when I try to do SELECT:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string** to the database?

Comment: And how the context is generated?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to your database? Most libraries require a commit after you save your record. For example in NHibernate, you can do record.Save(entity); and it will happily tell you it's been inserted, but you also have to call session.Commit(); afterward.

Comment: I am "committing", see question code, I am using: `database.Save(entity);`

Comment: I am using Entity Framework in a C# Console application.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us your connection string yet, and from your question, it's not clear if you see this behavior only when running your app from within Visual Studio or also outside of VS.

If you happen to be using SQL Server **Express** and the `AttachDbFileName=somename.mdf` approach, and you observe this behavior when running your app inside Visual Studio, then keep on reading.

The whole *User Instance and `AttachDbFileName=`* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: Connection string? It's all local. I opened up Visual Studio, opened my app, right-clicked Project name in Solution Explorer, added new MS SQL Compact Database, then chose the Entity model for it, then added tables to the DB, then updated theEntity Model so it has everything that's inthe database.

Comment: My DataSource points to the database file (that I created from within visual studio) whih is on my harddrive

Comment: My database is *.sdf - not *.mdf.

Comment: @Jase: thanks for the info - in your next question, you should mention relevant information like that right in your question to help us diagnose your issues!

Comment: @Jase: so are you seeing this behavior when you run your app **inside** Visual Studio? Or even when you run it on its own, from the Windows Explorer? The issue is most likely the same: VS will copy around your `.sdf` database file, insert into the copy of the `.sdf`, and then in the end throw that copy away - so the `.sdf` you're looking at isn't updated at all...

Comment: I have tried running it many times from Visual Studio, and also exiting visual studio and then running from all of the following locations: `bin/debug` `bin/release`, `obj/debug` `obj/release`, Also, you are right about VS. It creates copies all the time. There is a copy in bid debug, bin release, obj debug and obj release - _and then - there's the original copy located at the root of the project (which happens to be the one that is included in the datasource)_.