# Entity Framework Code First, It always makes a new Database

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, code-first

I'm new here and in Entity Framework too! i have a problem!

This is my Connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="SolutionName.DALClassLibrary.Setting.ShConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ASH.mdf; Database=ASH.mdf; Initial Catalog=ASH;Integrated Security=True;User Instance = true ; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And i wrote this ConnectionString in App.config in DAL project and setting of project too.

This is my context constructor:

```
public ASHContext(): base("ShConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ASHContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ASHContext, Migrations.Configuration>());            
    }
```

When i run the project in App_Data it makes a new Database with ShConnectionString.mdf name. But i have ASH.mdf database in App_Data already.

It can't find connectionstring or ConnectionString is wrong? or the problem in somewhere else?
Sorry for my poor English language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot save to database or retrieve (right info) from it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199547/cannot-save-to-database-or-retrieve-right-info-from-it)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong name to DBContext. Either use ***ShConnectionString*** as name in your configuration settings or change the name for DBContext to the one used in configuration.